# Godot: Possible to create a 2D tilemap and set it as a texture for a 3D surface?

Tags: 3d, textures, tilemap, godot

If I created tilemap of some sort of pattern or image and wanted to set it as the texture of a 3d surface or 3d model, how would I do it?

Comment: Quick question, do you have any experience with 3d softwares like blender ?

Comment: @suvam0451 I'm just starting out with blender. I'm just asking out of curiosity. Thanks for last time!

Comment: Yeah, in 3d software, you can just make a cube, break its UV aps, get any random image and tile it with it. Then you can bring it into godot engine. It is easier that working with shaders in engine itself.